# Proving supremum through continuity/limit arguments

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

The following is an exercise from *Calculus* by Spivak.

> Consider the set $S=\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R} : x^2+x-1<0\rbrace$. What is $\sup(S)$ and $\inf(S)$?

**My Attempt for $\sup(S)$:** Let $f(x)=x^2+x-1$. We show that $f(x)$ is continuous at all points $a\in\mathbb{R}$. 
Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. If $|x-a|<1$ then $-1<x-a<1$ and $a-1<x<1+a$ so $x+a+1<2a+1$. Choose $\delta_0=\min\lbrace 1,\frac{\epsilon}{|2a+1|}\rbrace$. 
Then $|x-a|<\delta_0$ implies 
\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(a)| & =|x^2+x-a^2-a| 
\\ & =|x^2-a^2+x-a|
\\ & =|(x-a)(x+a)+(x-a)|
\\ &=|(x-a)(x+a+1)|
\\ & <\frac{\epsilon}{|2a+1|}\cdot|x+a+1|
\\ & <\epsilon
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $a_0=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Because $\lim_{x\to a_0}f(x)=f(a_0)$ we have $\lim_{x\to a_0^-}f(x)=f(a_0)$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $a_0-x<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(a_0)|=|f(x)|<\epsilon$. If $x\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $a_0-x<\delta$ then $a_0-\delta<x$.

**Two problems:**

- I'm stuck after here, and I don't know if I'm proceeding with the correct methods at all.
- Even if this is not the right path for the proof, is my proof of the continuity of $f(x)$ valid?

Comment: I don't know either if that is the "correct method", but it looks weird to me that **you have to know** one of the polynomial's roots, because then why not apply the usual, high-school method of finding the roots of a "smiling" parabola, and then you know *exactly* where the minimal point is and when the maximal one for negative vlaues of $\;x\;$ .

Comment: There are several mistakes in your proof:  in the choice of $\delta_0$ you have take care of the case when $2a+1=0$. Also, $x<y$ does not imply $|x|  <|y|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solve $x^2+x-1 = 0$, and call the roots $a, b$, say $a < b$. Then $S = (a,b)$, and $\sup(S) = b, \inf(S) = a$

Comment: But how do I show that $f(x)<0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$?

Comment: @高田航: As veteran DonAntonio pointed out the "smiling parabola" has the part between $a$, and $b$ lying below the $x$ axis which means $f(x) < 0$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Many thanks.